# Which sides of an iPad does Apple Pencil 2 attach to?

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil

I have tried to deduce this from comparing product images online, but did not yet find a definitive answer to this:

Will the Apple Pencil 2 magnetically attach to (and charge at)

- only the portrait-mode, right-hand side (where the volume buttons are located),
- both of the "long" sides, or
- also the "short" sides of an iPad?

Furthermore, is it correct that the orientation of the pencil when attached (to whatever sides support it) does not matter for charging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205236):

The Pencil can be attached to the right side of the iPad Pro 11' or 12.9 (3rd gen).  Because there's no common left or right side, due to the lack of a Home button, either side will work.

The Pencil will magnetically attach to the center-right side of either long edge.  It will only attach to the iPad so that it lays alongside the iPad directly, not with part of it sticking past the iPad Pro edge (as in the picture, below).

[image]

*Update: Updated, based on comments, to indicate that Pencil charging is on the right-side only.

Comment: From experience it is one side only. The apple doc you say includes "attach your Apple Pencil to the magnetic connector on the side of your iPad Pro." "For iPad Pro 11-inch and iPad Pro 12.9-inch (3rd generation): To charge, make sure that Bluetooth is turned on for your iPad. Then attach your Apple Pencil to the magnetic connector at the center of the right side of your iPad."

Comment: "There is no common side"—you can still differentiate right from left because there is only one USB C connector, camera, set of face ID sensors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On my 12.9" iPad Pro, it is one side only. It is on the right side of the iPad Pro when the USB-C port is facing down.